# Viewing language (C/C++) reference/documentation in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

My first question on StackOverflow...

Does anybody know a way of viewing the reference/documentation manual of a language through CodeBlocks? Specifically for C/C++.

Example:
Say I want to look up the reference for strncpy(). In a very old Borland system (which we use at school) I would write the word and middle-click on it, thus being taken to its reference. It would also be nice if one can browse through the manual in some way.

Have I completely overlooked this (also searching google), or is it missing?
If it's missing, what's the quickest way of searching the C and/or reference manual without being online?

Regards!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  I'm not sure about the help files themselves though.

The procedure seems to be documented [here.](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Using_devhelp_as_a_help_viewer)

from the forums.

Re: F1 - help and function reference
« Reply #1 on: September 15, 2008, 02:07:59 pm »

if you have the help plugin installed, you can set help files through "Settings->Environment" and clicking on "Help files" in the list to the left.
The default file is called when pressing F1..
    Logged
starmaker
Newcomer
*
Posts: 3

Re: F1 - help and function reference
« Reply #2 on: September 15, 2008, 06:57:29 pm »

You are right but is there any up do date documentation ?

Now I use MSDN or cppreference.com web pages.
Regards,
starmaker

Comment: This is basically the way to do it. For the complete solution view my post further down.

Answer (score 4):

I found the complete answer. Based on your reply EvilTech.

Here's the setup procedure for different systems:
http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Help_plugin

And here are the help files for C++ compiled from an online source:
http://onnerby.se/~daniel/chm/

I find it strange though that I couldn't find any other help files for C "out there". I also had problems viewing the .chm files. The list of keywords of the file are shown, but the contents of each keyword does not show. Turns out this is comes from a windows security update. The solution is to right-click on the file -> properties -> click on "unblock".

Comment: @usar Sorry, it's been too long. I don't remember anything about this anymore :-)

Answer (score 0):

(BTW, do you mean [Code::Blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeblocks))

Having never used that, I can say anything definite, but have you tried selecting the term and pressing F1?

Answer (score 0):

Why not ask this in the forums of Code::Blocks?

Comment: I guess I'll try that next. I'll give this post a bit more time though