# How to view Opencv functions reference documentation in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, opencv, codeblocks

I am working on Opencv Project using C++.
Previously I had worked on opencv using `Java` and `Eclipse IDE`.
In Eclipse IDE, when you take cursor over the function name, the detailed documentation of functions appears and It gets easy to understand what the function is doing.

but now the problem occurs in `CodeBlocks IDE for C/C++` I didn't found any way to find documentation of functions written in editor window.

I have googled about viewing documentation for particular function and got a [*link*](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Using_devhelp_as_a_help_viewer)
and followed all steps mentioned but It didn't worked.

**error:** Couldn't find the help file. `/path/to/file/devhelp.sh`

If you have any workaround. Please Help.

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341345/viewing-language-c-c-reference-documentation-in-codeblocks look very similar.

Comment: @DineshSmokin This one didn't work for me.